# Linking Mulitiple Computers to Process a Task

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am unsure whether this question belongs here, so please feel free to migrate it if it doesn't.

My question is this, Is it possible to combine many different PC units to work as one?
Take for example, buying 3 different HP desktop PCs. Then link the hardware so that they act as one PC.

If so, please point me to some resources I can use.

Thanks for your time.

**Note**
I am not referring to linking them over a network, but rather, making the actual hardware work together.

I am not sure this is possible, so I am sure all my google search terms are not related to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should realize that linking them over a network does not obviate their ability to work together to complete a task. Most supercomputers and clusters today are interconnected via a network (albeit a very high speed one like Infiniband). The key is to have software that can understand that it's operating in a distributed environment (e.g. MPI libraries). You might also take a look at OpenMP or Hadoop. It really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for that word, "cluster". It was the key to solving my problems. Now google spits out relevant results for me. http://www.webstreet.com/super_computer.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about write an application that will be processed by those computers, you may be referring to [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).
You can use the [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) to do that, most of languages nowdays have MPI libraries.
You can find a more elaborated information about Parallel Computing on Wikipedia [Parallel Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) Article.

Answer (score 0):

You can not link some computer together to behave like one!!! Therefore you will need special hardware, which offers you the possibility to extend the numbers of CPU's working together. (Like a [cray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray))

Comment: So basically, i need to setup a new computer. Thanks.